# How to start user session (login user graphically) from CLI?

Tags: systemd, login, lightdm, loginctl

We can use `loginctl` in modern distributions with systemctl to control the user sessions, seats etc. E.g. with it is is trivial to [logout users](https://askubuntu.com/a/1261205/606016) and works on all desktop environments.

However, can I also do the reverse? I.e. I am at the login screen graphically and do have an SSH session/terminal/TTY.
Can I graphically login a user (in a specific seat,

And yes, I know I can of course auto-login a user session at boot, but this is not what I want, I want to login/unlock it *interactively* with the terminal.
If you need a reason for that to not call me crazy: In the use-case below I use VNC. VNC has [not the best security track record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing#Security) and as such can (often) only use 8 characters for a password, which is quite weak.
Now, I could of course increase the security by only booting to the login screen and then unlocking the session manually by entering a user password over VNC.
Yet again, many VNC clients/servers do not support clipboard pasting (out of the box, at least), so now I cannot enter, because I use a password with 30 random characters of course.

### Use case

1. Let's say I have a raspberry pi and [login via VNC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114572/119283), but I do have the "autologin" option enabled (e.g. for reasons described above).
2. I boot the device and login via VNC, as usual.
3. Now I login via SSH (which authenticates via public keys, which is very secure and convenient compared to VNC e.g.).
4. Now I want to unlock the session I see in VNC, with a terminal command, without doing anything on the VNC screen. As such, I want to enter something in the SSH session to unlock that other seat/session.

I hope this describes the idea/background behind the question in enough details, in order not to get any comments like “just do XY”, “what do you want to do?“ or so.

I want this question to be as broad as possible, because I think this use-case applies to any system/distro, but if you need a specific solution, consider the Rasperry Pi environment with `lightdm` and LXDE.

### Tries

I know I can use `loginctl unlock-session` to unlock a session. However, in my tests that only works when the user is already logged in.

Comment: Maybe `startx` ? It will bypass the display manager altogether but I don't believe there are other options.

Comment: It is ridiculous, loginctl can control everything except login. I need to investigate..